# Are int operations possible on GPU in Theano?

Tags: python, gpu, gpgpu, theano

So I have read that theano cannot do gpu computations with `float64` and to store ints as shared variables on the gpu they have to be initialised as shared `float32` data, and then recast to ints (like in the "little hack" in the logistic regression [example](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html))...but after such a recast, can theano do gpu computations on **ints**? and is storage a precondition for computation?  In other words, are the following two scenarios possible?

Scenario 1.  I want to do a dot product on two large vectors of ints.  I therefore make them shared as `float32` and recast them to int before the dot product, is this dot product then done on the gpu(regardless of int type)?

Scenario 2.  If scenario 1 is possible, would it still be possible to do the computation on the gpu without storing them as shared float32 first?  (I understand that sharing variables might mitigate gpu-cpu communication, but would the dot product still be possible?  Is storage a precondition for computation on gpu?)

Answer (score 5):

No, there is (currently) no way to do any operations on the GPU with any type other than `float32`.

This can be seen with this little demo code:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

x = theano.shared(numpy.arange(9 * 10).reshape((9, 10)).astype(numpy.float32))
y = theano.shared(numpy.arange(10 * 11).reshape((10, 11)).astype(numpy.float32))
z = theano.dot(tt.cast(x, 'int32'), tt.cast(y, 'int32'))
f = theano.function([], outputs=z)
theano.printing.debugprint(f)
```

When run on a GPU it will print the following computation graph:

```
dot [@A] ''   4
 |Elemwise{Cast{int32}} [@B] ''   3
 | |HostFromGpu [@C] ''   1
 |   |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [@D]
 |Elemwise{Cast{int32}} [@E] ''   2
   |HostFromGpu [@F] ''   0
     |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [@G]
```

Here you can see that the two shared variables are indeed stored in GPU memory (the two `CudaNdarrayType`s) but they are moved to the host (i.e. CPU/main memory) from the GPU (the `HostFromGpu` operations) before being cast to ints and a regular `dot` operation being used.

If the casts are omitted then you would see

```
HostFromGpu [@A] ''   1
 |GpuDot22 [@B] ''   0
   |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [@C]
   |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, matrix)> [@D]
```

Showing that the GPU is performing the dot product (the `GpuDot22` operation) but on floating point data, not integer data.

Comment: Really good answer, and I would definitely upvote it (but I don't have the required reputation :S).  According to this however,  in the ['deeplearrning.net' logistic regression example](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) it seems kinda useless that they first store shared_y as floatX and then recast to int.  According to your example above, this would then only increase the gpu-cpu communication.

Comment: The situation is, I believe, a bit different if the ints are used only as indexes into other tensors, as in that example. The problem arises when you want to perform mathematical operations on ints.